# Showing $2\Re{(a_{j}b_{j}\overline{a_{k}b_{k}})}=|a_{j}|^2|b_{k}|^2+|a_{k}|^2|b_{j}|^2-|a_{j}\overline{b_{k}}-a_{k}\overline{b_{j}}|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show 
\begin{align}
2\Re{(a_{j}b_{j}\overline{a_{k}b_{k}})}=|a_{j}|^2|b_{k}|^2+|a_{k}|^2|b_{j}|^2-|a_{j}\overline{b_{k}}-a_{k}\overline{b_{j}}|^2
\end{align}

which comes from  answer from [Lagrange's identity in the complex form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116091/lagranges-identity-in-the-complex-form), @math110.

Any guess or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** $2\Re(z)=z+\overline{z}$ and $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$.

The rest of it is only doing suitable factorisations.